# Regex missing a combination when / is added

Tags: regex

`/^\b(c\/|c(l)?(a)?(lle)?|av(eni)?(da)?|acceso|barrio|atajo|c(arre)?t(e)?ra|plaz(a|o)|b(o)?ulev(ar)?(d)?|vreda|tr(a)?v(es(i|í))?a|paseo|c(a)?m(i)?no)(\.)?(\s)?((de(l)?|a))?(\s)?((e)?l(o|a|e)(s)?)?\b\s/ig`

Matches combinations of: `calle/cl/ca/trva/travesia` etc + `del/de la/de los` etc in front of a word but it doesn't match:

"c/" in `c/ <word>`

"trva." in `trva. <word>`

Tried adding before/after/make it optional but it still won't match. What I'm doing wrong guys?

Comment: I assume the regex is continuous with no line breaks ? `\b\b` is redundant

Comment: @sln Yes, continuous. For example "C/ de la chopera" must match "C/ de la"

Comment: What language is this? Seems to be one that has regex literals, cause this wouldn't work in Python. Please [edit] and add the tag for it. Please also make a [mre], meaning example input, desired output, and actual output.

Comment: Problem lies within `\b` after `/`: "switch" between `/` and space is not a word boundary. Consider [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTkrRL/1)

Comment: There is no word boundary between `/` and space. Thats why it doesn't match `c/`

Comment: @demo You're right guys, it works. But it's important to have 100% match for those combinations at the beginning of string, if I remove \b, will it have a fail rate?

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/8MMtJg/1) is demo of cleared up a bit regex. I have no clue what it does, but I removed redundant `\b`, groups and alterations, and changed left groups to non-capturing ones.

Comment: You should bring your word boundaries inside pertinant optional clusters. Here's how.

Comment: `\b(?:c(?:/|l?a?(?:lle)?|(?:arre)?te?ra|a?mi?no)|a(?:v(?:eni)?(?:da)?|(?:cces|taj)o)|b(?:arrio|o?ulev(?:ar)?d?)|p(?:laz[ao]|aseo)|(?:vred|tra?v(?:es[ií])?)a)\.?\s?(?:\b(?:del?|a))?(?:\b\s)?(?:\be?l[aeo]s?)?`
https://regex101.com/r/gRIqLQ/1

Comment: @sln Brother that's a life changer, thank you very much! Had to add a ^ in the beginning to match the first combination only.

Comment: These `(\b(e)?l(o|a|e)(s)?)?` and `(\b(de(l)?|a))?` , and others that have `\b` should be closely examined for what the possible preceding character could be. These are mostly optional, however they will be a road block if not thought uot completely. I won't begin to know what you're doing.

Comment: @sln

`/^\b(cl?a?(?:lle)?|av(?:eni)?(?:da)?|acceso|barrio|atajo|c(?:arre)?te?ra|plaz[ao]|bo?ulev(?:ar)?d?|vreda|tra?v(?:es[ií])?a|paseo|ca?mi?no)\b(\/|\\|\.)?(?:\s\b(?:del?|a)\b)?(?:\s\be?l[oae]s?\b)?\s/gmi`

Managed to come up with this combination thanks to you guys - takes into account special symbols(./\)/words only/case sensitive/only the beginning of string